# Display value from Math.tan() in degrees?

Tags: java, android, degrees, radians

I'm learning programming for android and i made a calculator. The calculator is working fine but I'm having troubles with my sin, cos and tan formulas. I would like to display the values in degrees instead of radians.

Here is the piece of code that applies to that.

```
btnTan.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setValue(Double.toString(Math.tan(Double.parseDouble(txtCalc
                    .getText().toString()))));
        }
    });
```

And this is the function setValue

```
private void setValue(String value) {
    if (operator == 0)
        reset();

    if (readyToClear) {
        readyToClear = false;
    }

    txtCalc.setText(value);
    txtCalc.setSelection(value.length());

    hasChanged = true;
}
```

I would like to have another buttons that would toggle between radians and degrees like the Iphone calculator.

Thank you!

Comment: tan couldn't output a value of angle - are you talking about atan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double value = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString())));
value = ((double) Math.round(value * 1000)) / 1000;
setValue(Double.toString(value));
```

Comment: You mean atan right? tan would not make sense to change to degree.

Comment: I tried that but still not giving me the right answer! I tried with the tan of 45 that is supposed to result in 1.. but it give the answer of 92.8062... and if I use Math.atan I get 88.7269...

Comment: What do you try to do, the user enter what and you try to get what?

Comment: I edited my first comment with what i was trying to accomplish with the "answers"

Comment: ok you need to change 45 degree to radian instead I will edit my answer

Comment: The code would be more complicated with a toggle button. You need a label which you have to toggle between to radian and to degree and when the user enter angle in the edit text you have to check this label to know if you should change to degree or to radian.

Comment: Than you i did before the same as your answer but i got a answer of 0.9999999999 and i was hoping to get a value of 1

Comment: You can do that by calling round but you will loose decimal precision. So 15.20 degree would be 15

Comment: I tough about the round but i didn't wanted it to round everything.. how does the others calc get 1 as answers for tan(45) = 1?? I also tried other formulas like cos(120) that was suppose to give -0.5 gave me -0.49999999....

Comment: Say mutiply by a 1000 round and divide by a 1000

Comment: double value = Double.toString(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(txtCalc
                .getText().toString())))); Then value = Math.round(value * 1000) / 1000

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your help!! :)
Edit... 

Don't work! says that i can not use double it needs to be in string but if do that in string then i can't do the second part in the round! :(  Can i convert the string from value into a double then convert to string again?

Comment: Got it figured out! If there is a easier way to do it i would like to know!

String value = Double.toString(Math.tan(Math.toRadians  (Double.parseDouble(txtCalc .getText().toString()))));
    double result = Double.parseDouble(value);
    result = Math.round(result * 1000) / 1000;
    String finalResult = Double.toString(result);
    setValue(finalResult);

Comment: I don't think there is any easier way.

Comment: Well it worked but now I'm getting everything too rounded! if i put cos(120) gives me 0  :(

Answer (score 2):

[image]
and
[image]

so you can adjust you variables accordingly

```
1 radian = 57.2957795 degrees
```

Comment: it says display in degrees, and this is conversion for degrees